# Needing help with "New York" worldbuilding in 1920s setting

Tags: magic, urban-fantasy

I have been writing a fantasy novel for the past 12 years. The story is *mostly* finished (as far as the storyline and plot goes), but I have been having some trouble with worldbuilding. The story is set in the Jazz-era (the [Roaring Twenties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roaring_Twenties), if you will) and involves magic. It takes place in "New York" (but it's not actually New York). Whenever I've given people the material to read, they are often confused as to what time period it's taken place.

I have spent the past few months doing some research on the extensive history of New York, and particularly during the 1910s and 1920s, but have had some difficulty incorporating those into the story. Examples include methods of transportation (there is a parallel world where there are both magical and non-magical people living together), style of dress, etc. For example, one of the characters chooses to wear her hair long and loose, which is in contrast to the women of the time wearing it short (although, she is in her late 30s, and is more of a symbol of both her rebelliousness and stubbornness).

What architecture, fashion or other cultural elements can I include in my novel so that the reader immediately knows in the first few pages that this is taking place in "New York" during the Jazz era?

ETA: Thank you everyone for your suggestions! I will make sure to go through all of them and incorporate into my story!

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Is yours a worldbuilding problem or a writing problem? The way you phrased it makes me think it is the last one. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to make yourself familiar with this site.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll be reading up on the help center. Could you explain to me why it sounds more like a writing vs worldbuilding problem?

Comment: You wrote "How can I write in such a way where the reader immediately knows in the first few pages that this is taking place in "New York" during the Jazz era? ". This sounds a writing problem, to me.

Comment: I have placed the question on hold, so that it cannot be answered and you can freely edit it or move it to Writing.SE.

Comment: I think it is a worldbuilding question as is. I threw a couple edits in to make that more apparent? It is nominated for re-opening.

Comment: What about [History SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/) they might know too. This seems to fall into their category. In worldbuilding we think mostly of not realistic stuff :)

Comment: Have you tried "Hey there sport, care for a little Charleston while we look at this new style couch? What they call it again? Art decu? Deco? what a fad"

Comment: *Some* women wore their hair short (or shortish -- they wore it clearly longer than men). [Some wore it long](https://www.google.com/search?q=1920+hairstyles&num=100&tbm=isch). Just like women do today, except that the favorite shortish style was a instantly recognizable interbellic bobcut.

Comment: How close is your world to 1920s? Can you refer to real world historic events, real world persons and real world NYC's landmarks?

Comment: There are many books, websites, even museums dedicated to the 1920's.  Look up architecture, fashion, cuisine, infrastructure, and more.  If you can, visit New York and take a tour that emphases these things (I'm sure there are tours that will, the architecture if nothing else, or the nightclubs).  Your question reveals that you just haven't done the research.  If you believe things like women then mostly wore their hair short, you haven't even studied easily available materials.  It's like saying women in the early 1960's only wore short skirts.  You're confusing youth styles with fashion.

Comment: You have to remember that many people today won't actually know what it was like in the 1910s to 1920s. Instead they will jump to the closests things they remember and link it with that time period (probably the 50's and up). Without significant historical events, figures or inventions, the only way to establish the time would be to reference it multiple times. (Fashion and clothes trends are harder, because it requires people to know about the trends of an era which I doubt many people would know off the top of their head)

Comment: @Alexander Yes. Specifically, in the book, I have referred to speakeasies, and the latter third of the story takes place around the time of the stock market crash of the 1920s (though I took some liberties with each actual time it happened). As far as landmarks, I want to write it in a way where the reader will know, "Ah, that sounds like Grand Central" or "That sounds like Central Park" without it actually being those places.

Comment: @Cyn I actually do live in New York, and have gone on quite a few tours, as well as spent some time in the libraries. The vast majority of hairstyles I've come across during those time periods have been short.

Comment: Question looks better, but is still considerably broad. You're asking for help about architecture, cultural elements, hair styles, transport, etc. Please focus your query on one single issue only. It also looks incredibly writing-oriented, which is a no-no here. I mean, I don't live in the Great Pomme and have only passed through Qotham a couple times. I'm sure I could come up with several ways to get your readers to instantly recognise the City that Never Rests with its splendid aluminium spires of its temples to the gods of economics down along the Rampart Road without really trying. VTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cars

[image]

The [Ford Model-T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Model_T) was the most popular car in the world. In the early 1920s, more than half of the cars in the *world* were Model-T's. Production hit half a million cars per year in 1916, and a million cars per year in 1922, continuing at a high level until 1926. If you mention that Model-T's are all over the place, that pretty accurately places the story in the 1920s.

## Bob cuts for women

[image]

One of the key aspects of the [flapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flapper) style was the bob-cut (under a stylish hat, of course). Long hair for women could generally be considered the norm in Western society, from at least medieval times to modern. While most women (i.e. working class or rural) would have had long hair in the 20's, in a culturally savvy city like "New York" (or, even better, [West Egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_Gatsby#Plot_summary)) you'd run into a lot of young women with this distinctive haircut.

Comment: Bobcuts were [very far from universal](https://www.google.com/search?q=1920+hairstyles&num=100&tbm=isch)...

Comment: @AlexP Look at all the photos in the link that are actually photos from the 20s. They are all either bobs or those short wavy bob-like things. I don't really know how to define a bob, but short hair is definitely the style.

Answer (score 6):

A book isn't a visual medium, so the hair and cars are a start, but you can also add in historical grounding.

You're talking 1910s-1920s, so the biggest story there is would be WWI. References to that, and the after effects would be good.

Prohibition started in 1920, but your timeline is prior to that. So, you can add in the start of that political movement during the teens.

Women's Suffrage or the right to vote, is intimately connected with the passing of Prohibition laws. The women's Temperance Movement was THE issue of the day, and very connected to that.

There's also stars of the day--Mary Pickford, Lillian Gish, Charlie Chaplin, Buster Keaton. Pop culture references can't hurt. Hair styles were copied (just like the 1990s were the era of the "Rachel" cut).

One of the biggest films out-- *Birth of a Nation* in 1915. That's all about the KKK... *The Tramp* with Charlie Chaplin. there's also *Nosferatu* in 1922, and in 1927 the first "talkie" *The Jazz Singer*.

Yes, there are plenty of fiddly details you can include, but for it to be instantly recognizable to the reader, you need these sorts of historical touchstones. DON'T include the first version of the *Wizard of OZ* for instance, because hardly anyone remembers that, and any reasonable reader would date it to the Judy Garland era.

Answer (score 2):

How about over the radio cried memorable events of that time period:

https://www.timetoast.com/timelines/the-history-of-1910-1920

Like:

"The titanic has sunk, no comment from North Star yet"

Or

"The world iz in chaos in what can only be described as a world war"

"Woodrow wilson is president of the us"

"Otto von bismarks/prussian march across europe"

"Critics are raving about the blockbuster the wizard of oz"

Also a whole slew of prohibition events that would be very centric to 1920s NY.

Answer (score 1):

**Well-known people and phenomena**

"the man sitting opposite them in the **speakeasy** was holding up a newspaper with the latest headline concerning **Al Capone**"

Comment: Seems more like a comment than an answer. And this is very specific to just one portion of the time period mentioned (1910-1920s). He was a thing for about 7 years, and mostly from 1925-1932. Most news stories were specifically in the late 20s, and when he was on trial in the 1930s.

Answer (score 1):

Art Deco was huge in the 1920s. Think of ebony, ivory, and exquisite craftsmanship of many of the pieces of furniture during this time period.

[See this link for more information related to Art Deco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_Deco)

Hopefully that helps you a bit.